# Javascript cookie is not creating

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am trying to create a cookie when a button is clicked.But it is not being created.I have also tried with jquery cookie plugin but no luck.Here is my code:

```
  <button id="test" >Test</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

      jQuery("#test").click(function() {  
          document.cookie = "subscription=Anonymous; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT"; 
       });

     });
 </script>
```

Comment: as i see in MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/document.cookie, must put one by one cookie, not all at once

Comment: Works fine for me.  Perhaps you forgot to include jquery?  Where are you looking to see if the cookie was created?

Answer (score 0):

use `escape()` function because..

> Cookie values may not include semicolons, commas, or whitespace. For
>   this reason, you may want to use the JavaScript escape() function to
>   encode the value before storing it in the cookie.

and if you do this then you will also have to use the corresponding `unescape()` function when you read the cookie value.

If you do this,

Let me know if you still face problem :)

Comment: It works fine on my server .But not working on localhost .Don't understand why.

Comment: var domain = (options.domain && options.domain !== 'localhost') ? '; domain=' + (options.domain) : ''; try this to change domain

Comment: if not work fine then let me know again :) i try my best @AmitKollolDey